# How to get my activity to do something at a specific time

Tags: time, android-activity, clock

So if I wanted one of my activities to do something at a specific time and day how do I do so?
any quick description would be helpful. Im still very new at this and any help is very appreciated.

Comment: What platform are you working on? What have you tried yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your activities to run between some interwell you can use Threads in java.
If activities want to run at some sheduled time you can use TimerTask class in java.

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class ReportGenerator extends TimerTask {

  public void run() {
    System.out.println("Generating report");
    //TODO generate report
  }

}

class MainApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Timer timer  new Timer();
    Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
    date.set(
      Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,
      Calendar.SUNDAY
    );
    date.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
    date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    date.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    date.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    // Schedule to run every Sunday in midnight
    timer.schedule(
      new ReportGenerator(),
      date.getTime(),
      1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
    );
   // Schedule to run every Monday in midnight
   date.set(
      Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,
      Calendar.MONDAY
    );
    date.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
    date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    date.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    date.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    timer.schedule(
      new ReportGenerator(),
      date.getTime(),
      1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: quick question, what is Calendar.getInstance(). What does it do ? and thanks alot for replying :D

Comment: Calender.getInstance()  is used for singleton class creation. That
means only one instance of that
class will be created and others
will get reference of that class.

Comment: So Calendar is singleton class= only one instance of that class exists. cool! so what do you do if you have more than one alarm or notifier happening at different times? I thought id just call another instance?

Comment: there need only one instance of Calender.if you have diffrent shedules,reset the date and time.see my upadated answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Python program that would do whatever is in the my_func function accurate within the second. In this example it runs tomorrow at 12pm but target_date could be changed to any future date.

```
from datetime import datetime
from threading import Timer

today = datetime.today()
target_date = today.replace(day=today.day + 1, hour=12, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
delta_t = target_date - today

microSecs=delta_t.seconds * 1000000 + delta_t.microseconds
secs = microSecs / 1000000

def my_func():
    print("hello world")

t = Timer(secs, my_func)
t.start()
```

This code calculates the seconds between right now and the time you want something to happen, then sets a timer for that many seconds.